# Spinner com estados e cidades?

Tags: java, android

Como funciona um *spinner* com estados e cidades do Brasil? Ao clicar no estado, listar as cidades?

Qual a forma de fazer isso? Um banco com tudo cadastrado? SQLite? Preciso de um modelo pronto para estados e cidades?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta criar tabela (SQLite) com os estados e outra com as cidades, interligadas por uma chave estrangeira e os respetivos objetos claro.

Claro que convém já ter os estados e as cidades já cadastrados no banco.

Depois é só apanhar o evento do `spinner` de estados, fica o exemplo:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View view, int pos, long id) 
    {
        Estado es = (Estado) parentView.getItemAtPosition(pos).

        // Código de pesquisa na Tabela cidades das que tiverem o estado selecionado. 
        // Exemplo:
        ArrayList<Cidade> listaCidades = buscarNoBanco(es);

        // Depois é só adicionar a listaCidades a um outro spinner 
        // ou uma listView de cidades.
    }
});
```

Comment: obrigado, sabe onde encontro um script sql de todas as cidades com estados para sqlite? todos que encontrei da erro ao tentar importar no sqlite studio.

Comment: Podes montar um função que leia XML e grave no Banco, tens aqui os XML http://www.luiztools.com/post/Base-de-dados-com-todos-estados-e-cidades-brasileiras.aspx

Comment: Ou tens este script aqui: http://www.johnmarques.com.br/mysql/dump-sql-estados-e-cidades/

Comment: o problema que sempre que tento importar no sqlite studio esses script da erro de sintaxe.

Comment: Mostra-me o erro.

Comment: erro while  executing SQL:  near"*"  syntax error

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19118/discussion-between-jorge-b-and-war-lock).